# Is there a way to call the __d function in Cakephp 3 in a twig template?

Tags: twig, cakephp-3.0

I have installed `wyrihaximus/twig-view` in a CakePHP app which works fine except I don't know how to call the function `__d()` or any of the other related translate functions.

How do I access them?

## EDIT

Specifically when I call `{{ __('Hello') }}` or `{{ __d('Domain', 'Hi') }}` functions I get the `unknown __ function` or `unknown __d function` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordion with the doc [here](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView#functions), in the `Functions` section:

> __d maps to __d

So simply try something like this:

```
{{__d('my_plugin', 'Trending right now')}}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hmm. The obvious choice yet my browser throws the error: Unknown "__d" function.

Comment: very strange, may i check the wrong doc? Can you verify if you have correclty installed the library?

Comment: I used composer to install it. And generally it works but it just doesn't recognise the functions.

Comment: My bad. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't so must be my local config